# Postgresql service not starting on a Dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Dockerfile that will contemplate a group of services. **Yes, a container should run only one process**, but this container would be just for development and help to group this services and not for production.

The basic idea is to create a structure similar to LAPP (Linux; Apache; PostgreSQL; PHP). Apache is ruining ok and accepting requests, but the PostgreSQL is not starting. When a access the container with bash and get the service status, I get this response:

```
12/main (port 5432): down
```

My docker file looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y sudo vim postgresql postgresql-contrib 

RUN apt-get install -y apache2 php8.0 php8.0-cli php8.0-common hp8.0-opcache php8.0-pgsql php8.0-zip php8.0-gd libapache2-mod-php8.0

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN a2enmod php8.0
RUN sed -i 's/\/var\/www\/html/\/var\/www\/html\/public/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

COPY . /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html/public

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Building the image, I have the following message:

```
Success. You can now start the database server using:    
    pg_ctlcluster 12 main start

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log

update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/12/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
Setting up postgresql (12+214ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.19) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Removing intermediate container 57a7ed10215a
```

I tried to add this two options on the Dockerfile, but the service would not go up. I think the logs above give a hint about the service, but I do not understand init and SystemD yet.

```
RUN pg_ctlcluster 12 main start
RUN service postgresql start
```

If I attach to the container with bash, and execute the commands above, it works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: This feels like it should be split into multiple services in a docker-compose setup, as even in a dev env that would just make your life much easier

Comment: @John. Will do! But this is killing me, and I also think this answer can be helpful in the future

Comment: Trying to start postgres in a `RUN` command won't do you any good -- these are commands that run at *build* time, not at *run* time. You would need something to start the service when the container starts (e.g., as part of your `CMD`), but as @John says, you really don't want to try to bundle services together like this. Just use the [official postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) to run postgres.